# WiFi adapter works when directly connected, doesn't when plugged into hub

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I have only one USB port that works on my computer, and I usually use it for my mouse.

when I plug the Wi-Fi adapter into a powered USB hub, it doesn't work. However, it works fine when connected directly to the computer.

I tried it in Windows, and it works fine both through the hub, and when connected directly.

Any ideas as to why this strange behavior is occurring?

Comment: When you say 'external' are you saying it's a USB hub?  If so, does it have its own power source?

Comment: @bc2946088 yes ! it's plugged in my computer

Comment: @bc2946088 yes it's a USB hub and  it's plugged in my computer